# Get ID in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a User Table as below

```
TABLE USERS
user_id      user_name     user_rooms
1            PAUL          serialized and base64_encoded data (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
2            JOHNL         serialized and base64_encoded data (1, 2, 3)
3            MARK          serialized and base64_encoded data (3)
```

I need to create array from this table with **user_id** which have access to room, in this example to ROOM 3:

```
Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 3)
```

A query (soon switched to MYSQLI) is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_rooms FROM table_users");
$rooms = Array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $user_room[] = unserialize(base64_decode($row['user_rooms']));
}
```

`$rooms` return an array of rooms, I'm like to obtain array with user_id

Any help?

Comment: Why is `user_rooms` stored that way?

Comment: Switching to `mysqli` is a good idea, but even better is moving to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: What *exactly* are you asking here?  Can't you just do `$user_id[] = $row['user_id']`, just like you do with `user_rooms`?

Comment: Having serializeed data in a column violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule)
of [relational database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If at all possible, break that out into separate rows related to the user so you can properly query that.

Comment: @rocket, i need to perform next query with only users in array to populate table.

Comment: @user1504222: Oh!  So, you want the rows where `user_rooms` contains `3`?  Then you'll somehow need to search though that `$user_room` array you've created.  Or, better yet, normalize your database so that you can just query for those values.

Comment: Just normalise your schema.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
$data=array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $data[$row['user_id']] = $row['user_rooms'];
}
```

for access you can access like this :

```
echo "$data[index]";
```

Comment: That's not quite what he's trying to do.